Excel VBA renaming a sheet in VBA that was manually changed
I am new to VBA and am currently working on making template production sheets in Excel more user friendly for my company. The goal i for the user filling out the sheet to be able to input all data a certain way and then when it gets to our finance deptartment for them to be able to press a button to run a macro to pull the payroll information off the production sheet.
The issue I am having is we use the date as the Sheet name to track when speciifc production was done. So I can write the code and it works but then when it gets opened and the sheet name gets changed then the code no longer works.
So far, most of my time has been spent on Google trying to find out the best way to change the name of the sheets after they have already been declared in the code, but have not been able to find a solution.
I am hoping that there is a way to have the declared sheet name be a placeholder and then when someone manually changes the sheet name, the code can identify that and change the sheet name in the code to still run effectively.

A potentially better idea is to identify the sheet by its codename.

Microsoft documentation:

Worksheet.CodeName property (Excel)


Another (hack perhaps) is to put a named range on the sheet. Then you can get the range's parent (the sheet) - of course users might delete named ranges so we only do this for users we can put at least a little faith or trust in.

https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s112/microsoft-excel-vba-worksheet-sheet-name-codename.htm
